# Testing Target-Action wiring

Tags: iphone, objective-c, tdd

i came across the following [blog post](http://eschatologist.net/blog/?p=10) that explained the topic. However I do have troubles with the given samples.

It verifies target-action binding like so:

```
STAssertEquals([doSomethingButton action], @selector(doSomething:),
  @"The button should send -doSomething: to its target.");

STAssertEquals([doSomethingButton target], _windowController,
  @"The button should send its action to the window controller.");
```

This works as long as doSomethingButton is a UIBarButton. UISwitch or UIButton don't have a target or action property. I tried the following to assert on their target-action wiring:

```
GHAssertNotNil([[controller logSwitch] actionsForTarget:controller forControlEvent:UIControlEventValueChanged], nil);
```

However, it fails even though I have confirmed the action is properly called in the simulator. What is the right way to assert on target-action wiring for a UIControl?

UPDATE:

```
UIControl - (NSSet *)allTargets
```

seems to return nothing, even if debugging the application and executing it in the ***called*** action!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really seems to be a bug in the UIKit framework. I have filed a bug report to Apple.